# Can we replace existing null data with '' (Blank) to use indexes in oracle query

Tags: performance, oracle11g

I am working on query optimization and for example, create one index on EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE columns of EMPLOYEE table.

As per below query I want to retrieve EMPLOYEE Name is either 'SANDIP' (This pass from front-end parameter) And EMP_NAME IS NULL.

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE NVL (EMP_NAME,'A') = NVL ('SANDIP','A');
```

Above query doesn't use the index as EMP_NAME column contains null.
While below query uses the index.

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE (EMP_NAME = 'SANDIP' or EMP_CODE = '');
```

So Is it a good idea to define EMP_NAME as NOT NULL constraint and mark EMPLOYEE TABLE contain all existing NULL value with ''.

And What is the difference between '' and NULL?

Comment: "*And What is the difference between `''` and `NULL`*" there is none in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a_horse_with_no_name for comment. 
You are correct Null and '' both are considered as Null. So My second query uses index, but not considered the null value.

I have verified with below code.

-- Both are considered as null

```
Select * from  
(SELECT '' as a,'b' as b FROM DUAL union
 select null , 'b1' from dual )
where a is null
```

--No Row return

```
select * from  
(SELECT '' as a,'b' as b FROM DUAL union
 select null , 'b1' from dual )
where a = ''
```

Comment: Interesting observation. `select nvl(a,'null_val'), b...` and then commenting out the `where a is null` or the `where = ''` returns the same result.